# quebrar lista por tamanho python

Tags: python, python-3.x, programação-funcional

Hoje me deparei com a necessidade de quebrar uma lista de mais de 100 valores em uma lista de listas com no máximo 100 valores.

pesquisei muito, e no final acabei montando a função:

```
remove_list=[[]]
    n=0
    for i in remove_alarms:
        remove_list[n].append(i)
        if len(remove_list[n])>99:
            n=n+1
            remove_list.append([])
```

No caso estou recebendo uma lista com nomes de alarmes que devem ser removidos da Amazon e passando como parâmetro para a api que processa no máximo 100 valores.

A questão é que depois de demorar muito saiu essa linguiçona queria alguma dica de como melhorar ou utilizar algum função embutida do Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse é um caso típico onde é bacana usar a funcionalidade de "generators" do Python -

generators se caracterizam por responder ao "iterator protocol" - e como tais,  objetos que podem ser usados num comando `for` do Python.

Uma das formas de criar generators é escrever funções que tem a palavra chave `yield` no corpo. A expressão usada no yield é passada como valor para uma interação do `for`. Nesse caso, você pode criar um generator que recebe a lista grande como parâmetro, e gera como resultados fatias de 100 elementos:

```
def slice(biglist, slice_size=100):
    for i in range(0, len(biglist), slice_size):
        yield biglist[i: i + slice_size]
```

e para usar isso:

```
for list_slice in slice(biglist):
    # código para usar a sublista com 100 elementos
    ...
```

## O que são os geradores:

A ideia é a seguinte: uma função normal sempre é chamada, recebe parâmetros, cria suas variáveis locais, executa seu código (que pode ou não chamar utras funções), e retorna um valor - quando encontra o comando `return` (Funções sem um `return` em Python retornam `None` de forma implícita).

No momento de um `return`, todas as variáveis locais criadas pela função são destruídas. Inclusive os parâmetros que recebeu. Se for chamada de novo, a execução volta para a primeira linha da função, e ela tem que refazer todos os cálculos que já tenha feito de novo. Em termos de programação, se diz que uma função não tem "estado" - isso é, toda vez que é chamada com os mesmos parâmetros, vai refazer tudo, e retornar os mesmos resultados (claro, se ela mesma não fier outras chamadas que retornem fatores variáveis, tais como leituras de arquivo, aquisição de ddos da internet, ou de dados digitados pelo usuário (com `input`)).

Quando falamos de programação orientada a objetos, uma das grandes mudanças que acontecem é que objetos podem ter atributos - ou seja, entre uma chamada de um método e outra de um mesmo objeto, seu estado pode mudar.

Então, nesse caso, por exemplo - nos queremos ter algo que "se lembre da lista grande, completa", e que se "lembre" de qual foi a última "fatia" da lista que foi utilizada,  e que possa gerar a próxima fatia, e sinalizar quando a lista grande terminar.

Em orientação a objeto normal, sem as melhorias dos "geradores" que Python incorpora, isso poderia ser escrito assim:

```
Sentinela = None

class Fatia:
    def __init__(self, listagrande, tam_fatia=100):
         self.listagrande = listagrande
         self.tam_fatia = tam_fatia
         self.indice = 0

    def proximo(self):
         if self.indice >= len(self.listagrande):
              return Sentinela
         resultado = lista_grande[self.indice: self.indice + self.tam_fatia]
         self.indice += self.tam_fatia
         return resultado
```

E essa classe poderia ser usada para fatiar a lista, de forma parecida com o que fiz no primeiro exemplo, mas de forma mais "manual":

```
fatiador = Fatia(listagrande)
while True:
     pedaco = fatiador.proximo()
     if pedaco is Sentinela:
         # sai do while
         break
     # Codigo para usar a essa sublista
     ....
```

Agora, o `for` em Python, sendo um comando que ja sabe percorrer sequências ou iteradores, sabe "fazer uso" de objetos parecidos com o definido nessa classe. Sempre que fazemos um `for numero in sequencia:` no Python, ele pega o objeto na expressão depois da palavra chave `in` (nesse caso, a variável "sequência"), e chama o método `__iter__` desse objeto. (Se o objeto não tiver um método `__iter__` o comando  `for` tem um "plano B" usando o comprimento do objeto e índices numéricos, mas não vem ao caso agora).

O valor retornado por esse método `__iter__`, ele mesmo tem que ser um objeto que tenha o método `__next__`. Se tiver, então o comando `for` vai chamar esse método `__next__` uma vez pra cada iteração - e o valor retornado pelo método é usado na variável do `for`. Quando o `__next__` não tiver mais objetos pra retornar, ele levanta uma execeção do tipo `StopIteration`. Ao contrário das exceções que estamos mais acostumados a ver, como ValueError e TypeError, o StopIteration não indica um erro - e sim, é um sinal justamente usado pelo `for` para saber que aquele iterador não tem mais resultados. O comando `for` então acaba, e a execução continua na primeira linha depois do `for`.

Então, por exemplo, podemos adaptar a classe acima para funcionar com `for`, apenas um método `__iter__` e renomeando o método `proximo`:

```
class Fatia:
    def __init__(self, listagrande, tam_fatia=100):
         self.listagrande = listagrande
         self.tam_fatia = tam_fatia
         self.indice = 0

    def __iter__(self):e
        # Como essa propria classe contem
        # um metodo __next__ apropriado, 
        # basta retornar o proprio objeto
        return self

    def __next__(self):
         if self.indice >= len(self.listagrande):
              raise StopIteration()
         resultado = lista_grande[self.indice: self.indice + self.tam_fatia]
         self.indice += self.tam_fatia
         return resultado
```

Pronto, com essa simples mudança - antes era retornada uma variável de sentinela, cujo valor era comparado num `if` que tinha que ser escrito manualmente, e agora ele causa a exceção StopIteration. Objetos dessa classe podem ser usados como no primeiro exemplo da resposta:

```
for list_slice in Fatia(biglist):
    # código para usar a sublista com 100 elementos
    ...
```

Então, os mantenedores da linguagem, notando que esse era um padrão de uso comum, criaram a palavra chave `yield`. Sempre que ela aparece no corpo de uma função, a função deixa de ser uma função comum, e passa a ser o que chamamos de "gerador": internamente, ela funciona como a classe acima, e o Python  - quando chamamos uma função dessas, a linguagem já executa o equivalente ao `__iter__`, mas não executa nem uma linha dentro da função, e sim,  devolve um objeto que tem o método `__next__`. Quando chamamos o `__next__` (ou melhor, o comando `for` fa essa chamada internamente). aí sim, o código do corpo da função é executado, até o ponto onde encontra o primeiro `yield`. Nesse ponto, o valor dado ao `yield` é retornado como o resultado da chamada ao `__next__`. Quando o `__next__` for chamado da próxima vez, a funçãoc continua sendo executada na linha seguinte ao `yield`; todas as variáveis locais são "lembradas" - o yield funciona como uma "pausa" na função. Isso torna o código interno bem mais eficiente do que uma chamada "real" de função como a que acontece nos exemplos com classes, em que variáveis locais são criadas, etc...

Então, revisitando nosso gerador pra entender melhor:

```
def slice(biglist, slice_size=100):
    for i in range(0, len(biglist), slice_size):
        yield biglist[i: i + slice_size]
```

quando o Python encontra  `for fatia in slice(minhalista):` a mágica acontece - o Python primeiro cria um objeto "generator" com os parâmetros passados, e em seguida chama o `__next__` lá dentro - isso executa a linha com o `for` dentro da função `slice` - a variável "i" é inicializada, etc... na linha seguinte, a fatia da lista de "i" até "i + 100" é retornada, e é usada "fora da função", no corpo do `for` externo. As variáveis locais da função funcionam como se fossem atributos de uma classe, preservando o "estado interno" do gerador. (com a notável diferença de que, ao contrário de atributos de objetos no Python, essas variáveis internas não são públicas, e até podem ser lidas, mas não podem ser escritas por código fora da função geradora).

Você pode usar o gerador "manualmente" sem usar o `for` da seguinte forma:

```
fatiador = slice(biglist)
while True:
    try:
         fatia = next(fatiador)
    except StopIteration:
         break
    # código para lidar com a fatia aqui
    ...
```

Comment: funcionou mas e achei linda a função, mas não entendi como funciona, tenho apenas alguns meses de programação, vou dar uma estudada até entender.
Infelizmente não consigo dar upvote por não ter 15 pontos.Muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Atualizei com mais informações sobre como os generators funcionam

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo, consegui entender o funcionamento e tendo melhor performance vou utilizar sempre.